# Linux C signals

Tags: linux, multiprocessing, signals

I need to use SIGUSR1 and SIGUSR2 and read some text from pipe. One thread must read odd symbols, and another one must read even symbols. Main thread opens a .txt file and writes info into pipe, and 2 threads read symbols from pipe and write to their .txt files.
I tried to use sigwait, but it looks like it doesn't work correctly. Any ideas?
Thank you very much)

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <printf.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cerrno>
#include <signal.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
using namespace std;
static bool a=false;
static int c;

main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int fildes[2]; 
    char ch,ch1,ch2;
    FILE *fp,*f1,*f2;
    int stat,sig;

    sigset_t set1;
    sigset_t set2;
    sigemptyset(&set1);
    sigemptyset(&set2);
    sigaddset(&set1,SIGUSR1);
    sigaddset(&set2,SIGUSR2);
    sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK,&set1,NULL);
    sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK,&set2,NULL);

    pid_t p1,p2;
    pipe(fildes); 
    cout<<argv[1]<< " " <<argv[2]<< " " <<argv[3]<<endl;
    fp=fopen(argv[1],"r"); 
    f1=fopen(argv[2],"a");
    f2=fopen(argv[3],"a");
    int chet=2;
    p1=fork();
    if (!p1)
    { 
        do
        {     
            sigwait(&set1,&sig);
            read(fildes[0], &ch1, 1);
            printf("%c",ch1);
            fprintf(f1,"%c",ch1);

        }
        while(!a); 
        exit(0);
    }
    p2=fork();
    if (!p2)
    { 
           do
           {     
                sigwait(&set2,&sig);
                read(fildes[0], &ch2, 1);
                printf("%c",ch2);
                fprintf(f2,"%c",ch2);

           }
           while(!a); 
           exit(0);
    }
    else
    {
        while(!feof(fp))
        {  
              ch=fgetc(fp);
              write(fildes[1],&ch,1);
              if(chet%2==0)
                  kill(p1,SIGUSR1);
                else kill(p2,SIGUSR2);
              chet++;
              //sleep(1/10);
        }
        a=true;

        wait(&stat); 
        close(fildes[0]); 
        close(fildes[1]);
        fclose(f1);
        fclose(f2);
        fclose(fp); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Whay exactly happens? Looks like it doesnt work correctly is not enough information

Comment: One thing is wrong in your code: It doesn't have any error handling. Zero.

Comment: I gave him the credit that he removed error handling code from the question to make it more readable

Comment: @user2717954, nothing happens, if wait() function is not commented, program waits all the time, and if I comment it, program ends, and if I add something like kill(p2,SIGUSR2); in second fork, it shows me my text, but ALL text, nor odd or even symbols, so with information is OK

Answer (score 0):

`sigwait` and so forth work perfectly well.

However, you have two "classic" problems here:  first, an assumption of synchronized behavior that doesn't hold, and, second, buffering.

*Unsynchronized processes:*

First, for example, on my system, given a five byte input file, the parent process writes all bytes (including an EOF marker — whoops!) and sends all signals *before either child process even calls `sigwait`*:

```
[parent] read(5, "BaRd\n", 4096)     = 5
[parent] write(4, "B", 1)            = 1
[parent] kill(5404, SIGUSR1)         = 0
[parent] write(4, "a", 1)            = 1
[parent] kill(5405, SIGUSR2)         = 0
[parent] write(4, "R", 1)            = 1
[parent] kill(5404, SIGUSR1)         = 0
[parent] write(4, "d", 1)            = 1
[parent] kill(5405, SIGUSR2)         = 0
[parent] write(4, "\n", 1)           = 1
[parent] kill(5404, SIGUSR1)         = 0
[parent] read(5, "", 4096)           = 0
[parent] write(4, "\377", 1)         = 1                        # Oops! we wrote stdio's EOF marker
[parent] kill(5405, SIGUSR2)         = 0
[parent] wait4(-1,  <unfinished ...>
[child2] rt_sigtimedwait([USR2], NULL, NULL, 8) = 12            # Oops! child2 is going first
[child2] read(3, "B", 1)             = 1
[child2] rt_sigtimedwait([USR2], NULL, NULL, 8 <unfinished ...> # Oops! ordinary UNIX signals don't queue
[child1] rt_sigtimedwait([USR1], NULL, NULL, 8) = 10
[child1] read(3, "a", 1)             = 1
[child1] rt_sigtimedwait([USR1], NULL, NULL, 8
```

The children are *not* guaranteed to be ready as soon as you call `fork()`.  Moreover, it is *not* guaranteed that child1 will accept its signal first.  Indeed, in the above, it is child2 who accepts a signal and `read()`s first.  (Another complicating factor here is that conventional UNIX signals do not queue.  So, child1 will accept only one SIGUSR1, unaware of any previous redundant signals.)

*Buffering:*

I'm inferring that your second problem is that you see no output from the children, neither to the terminal nor to their output files.  This is simply [a mismatch between your expectations and those output streams' default buffering](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1716296/132382).  Change the buffering, or explicitly flush them, and you'll see that each child writes at least one byte.

Comment: what can I do with signals's behaviour?

Comment: @JeSa, you could have the parent signal the first child _once_, then have the children signal each other.